# Mediawiki, updating database from form in extension's special page

Tags: php, forms, mediawiki

I'm developing a Mediawiki extension. It's composed of a special page which has a form to be filled by the user. Using the data of the form, my extension should update a special table of the database.

The problem is that I don't know where to point the form. I cannot point it to something like `$IP/extensions/myExtension/processData.php` because I need to use the functions of the MediaWiki's  API, so it must be part of the wiki.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I'm sending the output of the form to the same page. You can do this either by leaving the `action` field blank, or filling it with the address of the page, using something like:

```
$this ->getTitle()->escapeLocalURL()
```

To process the data, you have to check whether there's a post petition present, and then parse the results and do whatever actions are needed:

```
if ($this -> getRequest() -> wasPosted()){
    $value = $this -> getRequest() -> getVal("first_field");
    // ...
```